# Is there a list available of all of the rules of acquisition?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, ferengi

The Ferengi follow 285 [Rules of Acquisition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rules_of_Acquisition), such as:

1. Once you have their money, you never give it back.
 3. Never spend more for an acquisition than you have to.
 6. Never allow family to stand in the way of opportunity.

What are the other rules? I can't seem to find rules 2, 4 and 5, for instance.

Comment: Those are two completely different and unrelated questions.  One of which is a list question, and not allowed on this site.  I've edited down the question body to make it an actual, on topic question that won't get closed.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rules_of_Acquisition

Comment: @Gilles Wikipedia's list doesn't distinguish between canon/non-canon Rules, see my answer.  There's a lot of conflict on its talk page about exactly what should be on the list, and it's apparently changed numerous times.

Comment: @Izkata FYI, list questions are allowed, provided they are a finite list that can definitely be answered.

Comment: @NominSim Take a look at the edit history...

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2091/2565

Comment: http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_Acquisition

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is General Reference.   A simple google search turns up the full list at Memory Alpha.  http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_Acquisition

Comment: @ThePopMachine [We no longer close for general reference.](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2400/31936)

Comment: @Null.   Really? I can ask "What year did TNG start?" or "What does TNG start for?"  and what?   It just stays?

Comment: @ThePopMachine Feel free to downvote such lazy questions to oblivion, but they should remain open.

Comment: Alright so there's no VTC for general reference.   But the mouseover for "downvote" is **This question does not show any research effort**  and the mouseover for "upvote" is **This question shows research effort**.   This should not be at +15.

Answer (score 17):

### The Rules of Acquisition

**The following is from a book by [Ira Steven Behr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ira_Steven_Behr) (ISBN 0-671-52936-6), with slight modification for academic and pedagogical purposes.**  A screenshot of the first twenty seven appears below.

The Ferengi are a fictional race of people that base their entire culture around commerce and profit. They have 285 Rules of Acquisition, of which the following are those known to others. They all have the rules memorized and will cite a relevant rule to justify their business decisions.

- One. Once you have their money, you never give it back.
- Two. The best deal is the one that brings the most profit.
- Three. Never spend more for an acquisition than you have to.
- Six. Never allow family to stand in the way of opportunity. (Alternatively: Never allow family to stand in the way of profit.)
- Seven. Keep your ears open.
- Eight. Small print leads to large risk.
- Nine. Opportunity plus instinct equals profit.
- Ten. Greed is eternal.

Behr's list is missing rules 4 and 5.

[image: Screenshot from the Book by Ira Steven Behr]

The Ferengi Rules of Acquisition. New York: Pocket Books, 1995. You once could download the PDF of the list from the book. Alas the link to the Pocket Books entry has died. You can enjoy another site which claims to [list them all](https://web.archive.org/web/20181124124206if_/http://www.treknologic.com/forum/index.php?topic=418.0).

Answer (score 11):

Memory Alpha lists all the known [Rules of Acquisition](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Rules_of_Acquisition) within the various TV series, out of a total number of 285, and includes references to which episodes they were stated in.  It's never been stated what the missing ones are, nor is there a complete list of all of them - Memory Alpha's list is the most complete there is that can be definitively stated as canon.<sup>1</sup>

There's also a set of "rules" listed that were either made up, or not known to be among the Rules of Acquisition - they're listed under "[Unofficial Rules](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Rules_of_Acquisition#Unofficial_Rules)" on that page.

Unfortunately for the second part of the question, rules 2, 4, and 5 have never been defined.

<sup>1</sup><sub>However, @Thaddeus's answer lists the rules as stated out-of-universe by one of the series producers</sub>

Answer (score -3):

Rule #1: Once you have their money, you never give it back.
Rule #2: The best deal is the one that brings the most proﬁt.
Rule #3: Never spend more for an acquisition than you have to.
Rule #4: Time and Latinum are precious.
Rule #5: Always exaggerate your estimate.
Rule #6: Never allow family to stand in the way of opportunity.
Rule #7: Keep your ears open.
Rule #8: Small print leads to large risk.
Rule #9: Opportunity plus instinct equals proﬁt.
Rule #10: Greed is eternal.
Rule #11: Even if it's free, you can always buy it cheaper.
Rule #12: Anything worth selling is worth selling twice.
Rule #13: Anything worth doing is worth doing for money.
Rule #14: Keep your family close; keep your Latinum closer.
Rule #15: Dead men close no deals.
Rule #16: A deal is a deal, until a better one comes along.
Rule #17: A contract is a contract is a contract: but only between Ferengi.
Rule #18: A Ferengi without proﬁt is no Ferengi at all.
Rule #19: Satisfaction is not guaranteed.
Rule #20: He who dives under the table today, lives to proﬁt tomorrow.
Rule #21: Never place friendship before proﬁt.
Rule #22: A wise man can hear proﬁt in the wind.
Rule #23: Nothing is more important than health, except money.
Rule #24: Latinum can't buy happiness, but you can sure have a blast renting it.
Rule #25: You pay for it, it's  your idea.
Rule #26: As the customers go, so goes the wise proﬁteer.
Rule #27: There's nothing more dangerous than an honest businessman.

Comment: Here's the whole list: http://noelgreen.com/ferengi/Rules-of-Acquisition.pdf

Comment: Hi, Zed! The extras seem to be fan-made, based on the link you put in your comment; if so, this doesn't really add anything to the other answers.